# Формула для генерации случайных чисел в отрезке

Tags: c#, функции, случайные-числа

**Задача:**
Придумайте формулу для генерации ряда натуральных чисел из отрезка [а; b], близких к случайным. Оформите ее в виде функции, сгенерируйте при ее помощи 100 случайных чисел.

Как сделать генератор случайных чисел, без использование различных функций? (чисто математическими формулами?)

Comment: А вы что-то уже прочитали про генерацию псевдослучайных чисел? Ну не Кнута, но хоть что-нибудь?

Comment: Да, что-то представляю про генерацию чисел

Comment: Можете вот тут почитать: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/432a2504bfe81977647fbe3db1a74d2d/pdm367.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Инициализация:

1. Выбрать два довольно больших взаимно простых целых числа `S` и `M`. Это константные параметры генератора.
2. Завести целочисленную переменную `C`. Это текущее значение генератора.
3. Инициализировать `C` каким-нибудь значением, например, системным временем. Если `C` >= `M`, то взять остаток от деления `C` на `M`

Генерация очередного псевдослучайного числа в диапазоне [0, 1):

1. К `C` прибавить `S`, и от суммы взять остаток от деления на `M`. Результат сохранить в `C`
2. Вернуть результат деления `C` на `M` как вещественных чисел.

Для преобразования случайного `R` из диапазона [0, 1) в [a, b) нужно вычислить `R * (b-a) + a`

Comment: Описанное выше называется линейным конгруэнтным методом генерации псевдослучайных чисел https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4